# IoT messages Publishing/Subsribing across regions (Endpoint in a different region)

Tags: aws-iot

I want to Publish/Subscribe (vis AWS IoT JavaScript) to a AWS IoT Endpoint which is located in another region.

Lets say I open a web page in USA which Publishes/Subscribes to AWS IoT topics to the AWS IoT Endpoint located at Mumbai(India).

1. Is this communication possible?
2. If yes, What will be the latency?
3. Will AWS reroute my messages within their own infrastructure?, Or my messages will be sent directly to Mumbai with automatic routing?
4. Any additional resources I need while sending IoT messages across regions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions on by one

1. Yes, this communication is perfectly possible. You can connect to AWS IoT Message Broker Endpoint of any region from any geographic location as long as you have access to valid credentials.
2. Yes, There will be latency.
3. No. AWS does not reroute any message within their own infrastructure. If you hit Mumbai region (`ap-south-1`), it will hit Mumbai region's endpoint only. Recently there was an article published about multi-region IoT solution deployment. You can find it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/provision-devices-globally-with-aws-iot/). This shows how to provision an IoT device based on its geographic location.
4. From the documentations:

> The topic namespace is isolated for each AWS account and region pair. For example, the Sensor/temp/room1 topic for an AWS account is independent from the Sensor/temp/room1 topic for another AWS account. This is true of regions, too. The Sensor/temp/room1 topic in the same AWS account in us-east-1 is independent from the same topic in us-east-2. AWS IoT does not support sending and receiving messages across AWS accounts and regions.